# SQL In Clause Value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  the following SQL

```
Select * 
from PS_VENDOR 
WHERE VENDOR IN ('111','222','333','444')
```

in which 444 VENDOR doesn't exist. but when I run the SQL I should get all 4 rows with all Vendors from IN CLAUSE and for 444 just populate BLANK or 'X'

I tried the following and it don't work

```
Select * 
from PS_VENDOR 
WHERE NVL(VENDOR IN ('111','222','333','444'), 'X');
```

Comment: You can't select values that don't exist. You have to "create" it somehow.

Comment: Just to remind you. When you ask a question and recieve an answer you should accept one of them if it is correct. You can also upvote useful answers. You already asked 7 questions and not accepted any answer. Such policy will discourage others to answer your further questions. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Am new to this group and so sorry. can you please let me know how do I accept the answers

Comment: @KumarG If you open a question posted by you and look on answers there are small ticks below score of each answer. You click o that next to best answer and that's it. When you accept one you will gain priv to upvote which you do by clicking arrow up next to answer. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour Then you can use that list: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6899211/kumar-g?tab=questions to accept answers in previous questions. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a CTE to hold your values, left join

```
with V1 as
(
select '111' as VV from dual
union all
select '222' as VV from dual
union all
select '333' as VV from dual
union all
select '444' as VV from dual
)

select VV, PS_VENDOR.*

from V1
left join PS_VENDOR 
  on VENDOR = VV
```